# Italics markup not working in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown-rendering

If I enter the following mark-down source:

```
“*blah*”
```

into a question or answer, then it works, but in a comment it doesn’t. The asterisks remain literal and don’t turn into italics.

Comment: *This* is *just* a *simple* test. "*Another Test*". " *Second Test* ".

Comment: I really disagree that this can be “by design”. It’s a real bug. The feature is by design; characters missing from the whitelist aren’t. @Bobby: you are using straight quotation marks, Timwi was using the typographically correct ones.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many edge case (in particular around URLs) to allow the full set from proper Markdown here; the two will never be identical in all regards.

However I'm willing to add characters to the "can begin or end formatting" whitelists that shouldn't cause any problems and that are valid use cases for appearing next to formatting.

For the next build, I have added the majority of typographics quotation marks to the list: single and double guillemets, single and double quotations marks (bottom, top 9-shaped, and top 6-shaped). The ellipsis is now allowed at the end of a formatted piece of text as well.

Answer (score -1):

comment mini-markdown is much, much stricter, and the characters adjacent to the italics or bold must be on the whitelist.

Unicode character U+201d `”` is not on that whitelist.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you elaborate this a little more, please?

Comment: Where is this _whitelist_ ?

Comment: can we somewhere find a **specification** for mini-Markdown?

Comment: Could you please add `“”‘’` to the whitelist?

Comment: I would, too, like to see “…” ‘…’ in the whitelist, and also «…» (typical French quotation marks) and „…“ (typical German quotation marks). Add 「…」 (Japanese and traditional Chinese) and you will probably support 99% of the [languages written on the Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks) and no one will complain for a while.