# Formatting at the beginning/end of links in chat must be explicitly not nested

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, markdown

In chat and in comments,

```
[*Felis catus* (domestic cat) Nucleotide BLAST](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ ...)
```

results in

> [*Felis catus* (domestic cat) Nucleotide BLAST](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&PROG_DEF=blastn&BLAST_PROG_DEF=megaBlast&BLAST_SPEC=OGP__9685__10703)

not the expected

> [*Felis catus* (domestic cat) Nucleotide BLAST](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&PROG_DEF=blastn&BLAST_PROG_DEF=megaBlast&BLAST_SPEC=OGP__9685__10703)

In order to get the expected/desired result, we can mangle the input to something that would make XML cry:

```
*[Felis catus* (domestic cat) Nucleotide BLAST](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ ...)
```

This is also a problem if there is formatting at just the end of a link, where

```
[om nom **nom**](https://www.google.com/search?q=om+nom+nom)
```

produces

> [om nom **nom**](https://www.google.com/search?q=om+nom+nom)

but

```
[om nom **nom](https://www.google.com/search?q=om+nom+nom)**
```

produces

> [om nom **nom**](https://www.google.com/search?q=om+nom+nom)

Comment: +1 XML made me cry a few times, thanks for the revenge hacks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added dashes, brackets, and curly braces to the list of characters that can appear next to formatting delimiters in Mini-Markdown. Since regular parens were already allowed, I don't see why their cornery and wavy brothers shouldn't be. This will work in the next respective builds of chat and the main sites.