# Dashes not on comment-italics-whitelist

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, markdown

For some reason I'm baffled by, [there's a specific whitelist of characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64706/italics-markup-not-working-in-comments) that can touch the special markdown characters (e.g. `*`) in comments without breaking them.  Can dashes/hyphens be added to this list?

Comment: Oh-*so*-bizarre.

Comment: You only find the existence of that list bizarre until people come complaining that "I think a*b is 42" doesn't come out quite as expected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be the case after the next build of the sites and of the chat, respectively.